# "'str' object does not support item assignment"

Tags: python

I don't understand what's wrong with this code. About half the times I run it, it gives me a 'str' object does not support item assignment error. The strings should be non-overlapping.

```
from random import randint, sample

board = []


for x in range(0, 5):
    board.append([","] * 11)

board.append(",,,,,@,,,,,")

for x in range(0, 5):
    board.append([","] * 11)

def print_board(board):
    for row in board:
        print " ".join(row)

x = sample(range(1, 11), 6)
y = sample(range(1, 11), 6)




board[x[0]][y[0]] = "A"
board[x[1]][y[1]] = "B"
board[x[2]][y[2]] = "C"
board[x[3]][y[3]] = "D"
board[x[4]][y[4]] = "E"
board[x[5]][y[5]] = "F"

print_board(board)
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Your runtime output would be handy. And you should explain what you want to get and what you actually get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the rows in your `board` are lists, but the middle one is just a string.  Try this:

```
board.append(list(",,,,,@,,,,,"))
```